# How to reload a page after recieveing a post request in flask?

Tags: jquery, sqlite, flask, websocket, jinja2

So currently I have two servers running, one fetches from a websocket and updates into a sqlite database and the other is the flask app which uses the same sqlite database to query and display the data in a jinja template.
I want to be able to reload the flask app when there is an update in the database.

What I tried doing is sending a post request through the websocket to a route which I created , and in that route I redirect it to the home page. It redirects it to the homepage but doesnt refresh the page , as a result which the webpage isn't updated

Sending a request to flask route

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO POST (ID,SOURCE,TITLE,URL) VALUES(?,?,?,?)" ,(value['_id'], value['source'], value['title'],value['url']))
conn.commit()
requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/update/1")
```

The flask route

```
@app.route("/update/<value>",methods=['GET','POST'])
def update(value):
    if value == '1':
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        return json.dumps({"value":0})
```

Another approach I tried doing was by rendering thorugh the route itself and using location.reload

Flask route

```
@app.route("/update/<value>",methods=['GET','POST'])
def update(value):
    if value == '1':
        return render_template("index.html",value=value)
    else:
        return json.dumps({"value":0})
```

Jinja

```
{% if value == '1' %}    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      location.reload();
    </script>
{% endif %}
```